# How to make avaudioplayer stop in a different class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

In my app delegate I have this code in the application did finish launching method:

```
NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                   pathForResource:@"appsong" ofType:@"m4a"];
self.audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];
audio.delegate = self;
[audio play];
audio.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

I have a page where another peice of music should play, how can i say that the avaudioplayer in the app delegate should stop and start again WHEN I QUIT THAT VIEW.

Comment: So you're trying to have music all the time, but different music for one page?

Comment: Exactly, this is correct

Answer (score 2):

Well since your global player is in your app delegate, the view that wants to play it's own music might add:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     // ...
     [(YourSpecificAppDelClass*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate pauseAudioPlayer];
}
```

and

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     // ...
     [(YourSpecificAppDelClass*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate startAudioPlayer];
}
```

where `startAudioPlayer` and `stopAudioPlayer` are exposed in your app delegates header file.

Comment: im getting an error for both: Reciever type AppDelegateClass for instance message does not declare method for //pause or play AudioPlayer

I probably have to declare it then, but how?

Comment: -(void)startAudioPlayer { // code to start audio player } in your appdelegate.m file and -(void)startAudioPlayer; in the .h file

Answer (score 0):

Call a function that stops the player thats in the appdelegate class from ur view class?